# Disabling specific weak ciphers and enforcing Perfect Forward Secrecy using JVM properties

Tags: java, security, encryption

I want to achieve the Perfect Forward Secrecy ([PFS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls)) by disabling the unwanted ciphers using JVM properties

I want to achieve this by using Java's 'jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms' property in java.security file.

Currently I set the property as below 
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, MD5, DESede, DH keySize < 1024, RSA keySize < 2048 and when I tested using the Server using TestSSLServer, I got the following output

```
  Supported versions: TLSv1.2
Deflate compression: no
Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
  TLSv1.2
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

I still couldn't find a mechanism to get rid of sites that don't provide PFS. E.g. ' TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256'.

Can I get this done by 'jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms'? If not, is there any other JVM level mechanism?

Comment: In what contexts are you trying to disable them?  What are you doing with the (non-disabled) cipher suites?

Comment: according to the blog post in [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls)  Perfect Forward Secrecy (PFS) is provided by anything on the Algorithm Standard Name list that start with TLS followed by a type of DHE. 

I want to achieve this by using Java's 'jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms' property in java.security file. So I want to remove the other ciphers which doesn't follow this rule

Comment: You have not answered my questions.  Unless you answer my questions, I can't attempt to answer yours.  And probably, neither can anyone else.

Comment: I think the reason is there :).Let me explain more, There is no any particular context, I want to remove the weak ciphers during the transport level communication for my web application. So to do this, what is the modification I need to do in the property jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms which will remove the ciphers that don't start as I mentioned above. i.e need to remove below ciphers 
 RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
 DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
 RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
 DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
 RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
 DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

Comment: You still haven't answered clearly (sigh) but I think your comments imply that context is making SSL/TLS connections for an HTTP / HTTPS stack.  Is that correct?   If yes, are you talking about server side or client side?

Comment: I have asked the exact same question at: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145855/how-to-enforce-perfect-forward-secrecy-using-jvm-properties. Still waiting for a proper answer.

Comment: Yes. This is the server side. See the question in StackExchange for descriptive explanation

Comment: @StephenC I have modified the question. Please let me know if you want to know further details

Answer (score 6):

I have been able to get forward secrecy to work in our Java server by changing this in the java.security file:

1) Uncomment (remove #) in front of

> crypto.policy=unlimited

(You will need at least Java 1.8.0_151 for this)

2) set jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms to

> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, MD5, DESede, DH keySize < 1024, RSA keySize < 2048, RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

(to get this list, I tested my site on ssllabs.com and listed all cipher suites SSLLabs said to be weak)

While you're working on this, you might also want to consider setting the following two variables when starting the java process, but that actually isn't needed to get forward secrecy to work:

> -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true